# Плавная смена цвета у TextView

Tags: color, android, анимация, textview

Добрый день! Есть задача: создать анимацию, совместимую с Android 2.x, которая за 30 секунд меняет цвет текста в TextView с красного на зелёный. Возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: Вот ещё прекрасное решение: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28239812 =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чём собственно проблема?
Создаём поток, в котором будем постепенно менять цвет.

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0; i<3000; i++){
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    textview.setColor(цвет);
                }
            });
            try{ 
               sleep(10); 
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Цвет желательно задавать в [HSL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL) или [HSV](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)) моделях (а потом конвертировать в [RGB](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB)(для HSV модели достаточно: [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).HSVtoColor(float []))), в них можно изменять тон цвета не изменяя его насыщенности и яркости.

Если хочется решение элегантнее, можно использовать [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 10) {

   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    textview.setColor(цвет);
                }
            });
   }
}.start();
```

Такое мелкое разбиение как у меня в примере делать не обязательно. Между зеленым и красным в HSV около 40 тонов в одну сторону и около 180 в другую (эти числа не точные, не помню какой разброс имеет тон в android). Делать количество итераций больше, чем количество тонов смысла не имеет.